# HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://api.powerml.co/v1/llama/data on the lamini Colab notebook for a simple finetuning of a LLM

Tags: python, large-language-model

I am learning to finetune/train a model and started using the Lamini Colab notebook called finetuning.ipynb.
The code segments in the notebook were executing fine until recently. From yesterday, i have been getting the above http error.
Can anyone help me with this ?

Here is the code:

```
### Cell 1 ###
# @title Step 1: Authenticate with Google
# @markdown Note: You will be asked to sign in with Google, connected to your Lamini account.

from google.colab import auth
import requests
import os
import yaml

def authenticate_powerml():
    auth.authenticate_user()
    gcloud_token = !gcloud auth print-access-token
    powerml_token_response = requests.get('https://api.powerml.co/v1/auth/verify_gcloud_token?token=' + gcloud_token[0])
    print(powerml_token_response)

    return powerml_token_response.json()['token']

key = authenticate_powerml()

config = {
    "production": {
        "key": key,
        "url": "https://api.powerml.co"
    }
}

keys_dir_path = '/root/.powerml'
os.makedirs(keys_dir_path, exist_ok=True)

keys_file_path = keys_dir_path + '/configure_llama.yaml'
with open(keys_file_path, 'w') as f:
    yaml.dump(config, f, default_flow_style=False)

### Cell 2 ####
!pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --ignore-installed lamini==0.0.19

### Cell 3 ###
!wget -q -O "seed_lamini_docs.jsonl" "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1SfGp1tVuLTs0WYDugZcxX-EHrmDtYrYJ"

!wget -q -O "seed_taylor_swift.jsonl" "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=119sHYYImcXEbGyvS3wWGpkSEVIFdLy6Z"

!wget -q -O "seed_bts.csv" "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1lblhdhKwoiOjlvfk8tr7Ieo4KpvjRm6n"

!wget -q -O "seed_open_llm.jsonl" "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1S7oPPko-UmOr-bqkZ_PREfGKO2f73ZiK"

### Cell 4 ###
from llama import QuestionAnswerModel

import time

# Instantiate the model and load the data into it
finetune_model = QuestionAnswerModel()

finetune_model.load_question_answer_from_jsonlines("seed_lamini_docs.jsonl")

### Cell 5 ###`enter code here`
# Train the model
start=time.time()

finetune_model.train(enable_peft=True)   ## <--------- Here is the error

print(f"Time taken: {time.time()-start} seconds")
```

Comment: https://lamini-ai.github.io/DeveloperNotes/lamini_v2_api_migration/

Comment: Thanks @gre_gor. This migration doc provides the info as to why the .../v1/llama/data url was throwing a 404 error since they have removed all datasets from /v1 api according to the migration doc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @gre_gor for pointing to the lamini api migration from v1 to v2. i followed the link to the 'lamini free training' in the path given by @gre_gor's comment, and was able to successfully execute the training tutorial. "https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1F7XkfN5_VLlhr5zIG3SdK_sUqo4Wr7bE".